# scope with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table of doctors, doctors have doctor_id, hospital_id, dept_id

How do I write a scope where I can say: Select all the doctores who have the same hospital_id same dept_id as the current doctor_id but don't include this current doctor_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is as a scope:

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.other_docs_in_dept(doc)
    Doctor.where(dept_id: doc.dept_id)
          .where(hospital_id: doc.hospital_id)
          .where("id != #{doc.id}")
  end
end
```

... but this may work better for you as an instance method:

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  def other_docs_in_dept
    Doctor.where(dept_id: dept_id)
          .where(hospital_id: hospital_id)
          .where("id != #{id}")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question. If each of these doctors has a profile in doctor_profiles. How do I through eager loading retrieves all the user profiles too.

Comment: If Doctor `has_one :profile` then [**`.includes(:profile)`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: @Mori Regarding the class method `self.other_docs_in_dept`: the method would raise a `RuntimeError` if `doc` is `nil`.